# AC-Coupling blocking negative voltage values

Tags: transistors, amplifier, electret, condenser-microphone

This question is about the amplification of an electret microphone signal

In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SToBPCajwc0&t=615s

He is using an AC-Coupling capacitor to block the DC component and then a transistor to amplify the signal.

[image]

At the 9:20 mark, he says that the negative voltage values would be cut off after going through the AC-Coupling Capacitor. I can't think why AC-Coupling would block negative values. Is it actually that the transistor would block the negative values? Or is he thinking further ahead about an ADC on a soundcard not accepting negative voltage signal values?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to post a screen grab of the schematic used in that tutorial. The sound card has to accept alternating polarity signals as that's what any audio from a phone, etc., will be.

Comment: I understand now, it's because the transistor also acts a switch so insufficient or negative voltage supplied to the base will turn off the transistor and no signal will be transmitted through the transistor

Comment: @Transistor, I will do that in future

Comment: Why not do it now to make your question useful to others? Give something back to the site ...

Comment: You're right, I'll do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guy in the video misspoke. It's the transistor that's cutting off half of the waveform, because of how it's biased. The blocking capacitor simply eliminates the bias that's already on the microphone signal.